# Zend Framework display custom error when bootstrap throw exception

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling, bootstrapping

I am currently using Zend Framework 1.  In bootstrap i will have

> protected function _initLogger()
>      {
>
> > ```
> >   //this is where I create log to file
> > ```
> >
> > }

The issue is when the log file have write protected or have issue the error will display to browser with directory location etc.

I don't want to suppress the message but how can I custom this error so it will not show too much information

my application.ini

> phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
>   phpSettings.display_errors = 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**Tell Zend Framework to not handle exceptions. Do this in your application.ini**

```
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 1
```

**Do following in your Bootstrap class.**

**Define a custom method to handle exceptions.**

```
public function __handleExceptions(Exception $e){
        //render a view with a simple error message for the user
        //and send an email with the error to admin
    }
```

Override the `_bootstrap()` and `run()` methods of `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap` in your Bootstrap class and catch the exceptions thrown during the bootstrap process or while running the application and call your exception handler as shown below.

```
    protected function _bootstrap($resource = null)
    {
        try {
            parent::_bootstrap($resource);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $this->__handleExecptions($e);
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        try {
            parent::run();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $this->__handleExecptions($e);
        }
    }
```

This should handle all your exceptions. For handling errors register your own error handler as shown below.

```
public function _initErrorHandler(){
        set_error_handler(array($this, '__hanleErrors'));
}

public function __hanleErrors($errNo, $errStr, $errFile, $errLine){
        //render a view with a simple error message for the user
        //and send an email with the error to admin
    }
```

Now as you manually handle both errors and exceptions you can show user a simple message (by rendering a view) and email technical details to admin.

Hope this helps.